# (Firebase,js) Problem with creating document that have userID as documentID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So i'm working on registration system using firebase authentication and this is what i want to achieve is:

1. user registers with name,surname,email and password(for that im using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`)
2. once user registered, system creates document in collection "users", that documentID matches registered userID.
   3.That newly created document create fields: name and surname based on user input.

I'm currently stuck at the moment of creating document and i don't know how to make it work properly.

Finally i ended up with this:

```
signupForm.addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  const name = signupForm.name.value;
  const surname = signupForm.surname.value;
  const email = signupForm.email.value;
  const password = signupForm.password.value;
  
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(cred => {
      signupForm.reset();
      userId = cred.user.uid;
      
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  
  setUserData(userId,name,surname);
});

function setUserData(userId,name,surname){
  const userRef = doc(db,"users",userId);
  setDoc(userRef,{
    name: name,
    surname: surname
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  });
}
```

it throws:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1.

I tried many solutions from stackoverflow and even chatGPT, nothing works. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `setUserData` *before* the user account is created, *before* `userId` has a value. If you add log statements all around your code, you'll see the order in which things execute.

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, like all JS functions that return a promise, is asynchronous and returns immediately before the work is complete.  The `then` and `catch` callbacks are also asynchronous and return promises, and are invoked some time later.  If you want to do something that depends on knowing the newly created user's UID, you need to do that inside the `then` callback.

```
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(cred => {
      signupForm.reset();
      userId = cred.user.uid;
      setUserData(userId,name,surname);  // call setUserData here with the userId
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
```

Comment: nothing happend, i even put console.log("test"); right above setDoc() in setUserData. it Didn't print out.

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happened?"  Something must have happened, otherwise the code didn't run at all.

Comment: ahh yes, wasted half day only beacuse i used const instead of let for userId... Now it works as intended. That catch in createUserWithEmailAndPassword pointed it out, but i was ignoring it. Anyway thank you for your effort here.